# Ubuntu 18.04 freezes

Tags: 18.04, freeze

Recently I upgraded my laptop from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS. Everything is working perfectly fine but my computer freezes while doing something, dealing with virtual machines to be more specific. The mouse cursor moves but nothing on desktop responds. If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, it locks the system and once I unlock the system again, everything remains frozen as it was.

I would provide any information if necessary. Also, I didn't had such issue in Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Please add information about  your virtualization software. Do you use Virtualbox, KVM/Qemu, VMware, …? Do you use the latest version? Where did you get the version you're using from?

Comment: I use Virtualbox and installed it from Ubuntu repository. The version is 5.2.10

Comment: Can you login on a differnt TTY? e.g. Ctrl+Alt+F4. If it works, post the output of `dmesg`

Answer (score 1):

Virtualbox recently had a few problems with newer kernels. It might be worth trying to use the latest version directly from [virtualbox.org](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads).

To do so, please uninstall the Ubuntu version of Virtualbox, e.g. using apt:

```
$ sudo apt remove virtualbox
```

Then, download the package file from virtualbox.org and install it using a package manager of your choice, e.g. using dpkg:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-5.2_5.2.12-122591~Ubuntu~bionic_amd64.deb
```

Make sure all necessary dependencies are installed:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
```

Reboot and try running your VM again.

Comment: Hi @drc, I followed these instructions and installed virtualbox from their website. The problem was not there yesterday but I faced the same problem today.

Comment: Please update your post with that information. Please include the output of `dkms status` and `journalctl -u vboxdrv.service` and provide the VBox.log of the VM you tried to run as per the [Virtualbox manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch12.html#collect-debug-info).

Answer (score 0):

The only way around that would be to reboot and log in via tty.  From there,  see if Apport is installed.  You could try the following:

"sudo apt list --installed | grep apport".

If it isn't, try the line below and follow the prompts

"sudo apt install apport"

If it was already installed, change directories to /var/crash, and take a look at the files(if any exist.)  If any, they were automatically generated by Apport when something weird happened.

If a report from Apport doesn't exist for what your experiencing, it may not be a crash, but a shortfall coming from something else.

By default Apport is disabled, so it would be  good idea to add a hashtag "#" to line 23 of crashdb.conf, located in /etc/apport.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: By reading the diagnostic printout from apport, you may be able to figure out what is causing your computer to freeze.  Apport gives you a snapshot of your computer a second or two before an event etc....

Comment: This answer does not helped me. After that freeze, there is nothing in `/var/crash` even if apport is installed. It's not a crash.