# Ubuntu 18.04 screen always freezes with Google Meets

Tags: 18.04, freeze, video-player, opera, video-streaming

Every single time I am on a meeting on Google Meets, my Ubuntu crashes. The sound and mouse keep working, but the screen freezes. I use Opera Web Browser, and in addition to the browser with Google Meet running, I usually have atom and the terminal itself running - not a big deal.

Does anyone have a clue of why that is happening and how to fix it? Could it be a problem with Opera or Google Meets specifically? And when the screen freezes, what should I do? <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>del</kbd> to force quit Opera?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Is this your question ? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038071/ubuntu-18-04-freezes?rq=1

Comment: Please test with another browser to see if the problem is Opera-specific, specific to your Opera user configuration, or more general in nature. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: I got similar issue twice. 

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and in Mozilla Firefox browser, while i tried to share my whole screen. I got popup to allow sharing. Before clicking on "Allow" my laptop got freezed. Keyboard, mouse nothing worked. I could hear meeting voice for few seconds but later that is also stopped.
I needed to forcefully shutdown my laptop.

Comment: Copy that, exactly the same problem, but it happens very rarely.

Comment: What to do -other than reboot- in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with Ubuntu 18.04 and Mozilla Firefox. When I tried to share screen my computer got freezed while allowing access to window. I use Dark Reader add-on, and the problem somehow got resolved when I disabled it. Now I can enable it again and share screen whithout problems.

Answer (score 0):

As described in [ino's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1047576/618353) in [How to restart GNOME Shell from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/q/100226/618353):

> In the case where the whole GNOME Shell got frozen, there is a way to restart it from the terminal without restarting the whole X window:
>
> 1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to switch to a TTY terminal.
> 2. Log in with your credentials (username and password) and then run:
>
>    ```
>    DISPLAY=:0 gnome-shell -r &
>    ```
> 3. Log out by running:
>
>    ```
>    exit
>    ```
> 4. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to switch back to a graphical X windows session.